# Union two DataFrames of different types in Spark

Tags: arrays, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql, union

In my recent project, I need to union two dataframes of different sizes.
For example:

Here is my sample data:

df1:

```
name    number    address
kevin   101        NZ
gevin   102        CA
```

here all the fields are of type String.

df2:

```
name    number    address
kevin   [101,102]    NZ
gevin   [102,103]    CA
```

Here name and address are type string and number is of type `array<string>`.

Now I need to union these two dataframes. My expexcted outcome is like:

```
name    number    address
kevin   101         NZ
gevin   102         CA
kevin   [101,102]   NZ
gevin   [102,103]   CA
```

final df types should be same as the df2(string, array, string).

Answer (score 1):

You can convert to `array` for the first dataframe as well and `union` both dataframe.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

df1.withColumn("number", array($"number"))
   .union(df2)
```

Output:

```
+-----+----------+-------+
|name |number    |address|
+-----+----------+-------+
|kevin|[101]     |NZ     |
|gevin|[102]     |CZ     |
|kevin|[101, 102]|NZ     |
|gevin|[102, 103]|CZ     |
+-----+----------+-------+
```

Hope this helps!